# How can I fix Python/Django migrate error

Tags: python, django

I had migrated error.
Please give me any advance thanks.
And here is my related cod and error.

migration/0001_initial_.py

```
operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Member',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
                ('content', models.TextField()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

models.py

```
 class Member(models.Model):

    name        = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content     = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name`
```

serialize class

```
class MembersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'content')
```

Error traceback:

```
 "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\bin\runnerw.exe" E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" migrate E:/Full-stack-project/react-django-practise/back_end
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
Operations to perform:
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 52, in 
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, members, sessions, sites, socialaccount
    run_command()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 46, in run_command
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "c:\program files\python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "c:\program files\python36\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:/Full-stack-project/react-django-practise/back_end\manage.py", line 15, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 163, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 210, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 271, in __init__
    self.render_multiple(list(models.values()) + self.real_models)
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 306, in render_multiple
    model.render(self)
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 567, in render
    body = {name: field.clone() for name, field in self.fields}
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 567, in 
    body = {name: field.clone() for name, field in self.fields}
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 493, in clone
    name, path, args, kwargs = self.deconstruct()
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 928, in deconstruct
    name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
  File "E:\Full-stack-project\react-django-practise\back_end\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 464, in deconstruct
    value = getattr(self, attr_overrides.get(name, name))

AttributeError: 'AutoField' object has no attribute 'api
```

Comment: That error is not coming from this code. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: thanks for replying. 
So what code would you like to see ? I can show anything. thanks.

Comment: The traceback that came with the error.

Comment: Here is full tracebook.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vTgr9NU39bDjEwKcYeSYFYlX-tzp0b70sR0lfJ-l4Yk/edit